# Crackling noise in mic recordings

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, 21.10, audio-recording

This one is pretty strange. Whenever I'm recording my voice with a mic, there are noticeable crackling noises in the background. No matter what app I'm using for voice recording, but I was testing it mainly in Audacity.

HOWEVER if I turn off my sound card profile in Pulse Audio, and select sound card directly as an input device in Audacity, then the quality is perfect, which suggests to me, that there is some processing going on that distorts the signal.

Crackling settings:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Not crackling settings:

[image: Screenshot 2]

The issue is that every app using the microphone, is using these "default" crackling settings, because enabled Pulse Audio profile is required.

Any ideas how to fix this?

**Added #1:**

I tried solutions from https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Static_noise_in_microphone_recording but they didn't help.

Comment: Good start but you should add the version details of the software(s) you use.